# CUT Command in AIX for non breaking line character

Tags: unix, aix

I have a cut command the needs to be executed in AIX.

The cut command runs on few lines which have non breaking character �

when i try to cut a line say in normal unix box
line: this is a test� example 1
Command: `cut 1-20`
Output: this is a test� examp

But in AIX i get the result as
Output in AIX: this is a test� exa

How to fix this!?

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with the UTF8 encoding. Try the command adding the -B flag.

Comment: `LC_CTYPE` might be not properly set for UTF8. Or UTF8-support might be not installed. Anyways, it is safe to set `LC_CTYPE=C` and specify length in bytes not characters.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond my current value of the variable is LC_CTYPE="en_GB" should i override or can i have both?

Comment: tried setting LC_CTYPE=C, still it did not worked @LorinczyZsigmond

Comment: alternatively you can use `colrm` command if its available on your system.

Comment: Different versions of `cut(1)` handle multibyte characters differently. Most common is simply handling bytes, not characters. Perhaps `sed(1)`  could be used instead `export LC_CTYPE=EN_GB; sed 's/^\(.\{20\}\).*/\1/'` for utf8 version.

Comment: Do you get different results from `wc -c`? Can you do something like `echo "${line}" | tr "�" "\r" | cut -c1-20 "| tr "\r" "�"` ?

Comment: An AIX _is_ a "normal" UNIX box. Don't confuse Linux/GNU with UNIX!